# converting random to int C#

Tags: c#, random, iterator

I'm trying to generate a random integer which is responsible for selecting information from the array given below, in this case it's supposed to get a question (1 to 5) and store it in the string.

But I can't seem to convert the random to int. Does anyone have suggestions on a possible solution?

```
Random rand = new Random().Next(1, 5);
int randNum = rand.Next(1, 5);
string questString = questions.GetValue(quest, randNum);
```

Comment: `Next` returns an `int` not `Random` so your code doesn't compile

Comment: _Random rand = new Random();_ only then you ask for Next

Comment: Note that `.Next(1,5)` returns 1, 2, 3 or 4. Never 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your random object is wrongly initialized, calling the function **Next(1, 5)** will return an integer and not an instance of the random

you need to do

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randNum = rand.Next(1, 5);
string tekstvraag = vragen.GetValue(vraag, randNum);
```

Answer (score 6):

Set `rand` to `new Random()`...not `new Random().Next(1, 5);`

```
Random rand = new Random();

int randNum = rand.Next(1, 5);

string tekstvraag = vragen.GetValue(vraag, randNum);
```